# Converting JSON txt file to XML

Tags: json, xml, formatting, converters

We're constructing a network of data and part of that includes modifying a search query from a public website to pull all of the data we want. That data, however, when pulled is stored into a JSON txt file.

Ultimately we want this data to be stored in an Access Database so the next step, we thought, was to convert it to XML so we can have an Excel sheet to import. We found a formatting tool (http:jsonformatter.org). When running the tool we received the following error:

```
“Microsoft Access has encountered an error processing the XML schema in file ‘Data.xml’,
A document must contain exactly one root element”
```

I've no idea what this entails or where to start debugging. Are there alternatives we might consider?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that there is more than one root element. Have you validated the XML generated? I looked at the website. I tried to ask via comment but I don't have enough rep but you should post some of your json and xml.

If I am reading your issue correctly, you are converting json to xml format and then to excel?

I would suggest writing some code to consume the json and export the xml files to import.